# JSF Mysql Login. Problems getting data from mysql

Tags: mysql, jsf, jdbc

I am new to jsf and trying to learn to create login system  that verifies the username and password from mysql database. When I run this code, it goes to the failure login page even if the login details are correct. The value of DbUsername and Dbpwd is displayed null in label.

Index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    
 /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">


   <head><title>JSF Login</title></head>
 <body>
     <h1>Login</h1>
 <h:form>
<table>
 <tr>
<td><h:outputText value="Username: " /></td>
<td><h:inputText id="loginname" 
 value="#{login.userName}" />
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h:outputText value="Password: " /></td>
<td><h:inputSecret id="password" 
value="#{login.password}" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td><h:commandButton value="Login" 
action="#{login.checkLogin}"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
   <h:outputLabel value="#{login.label1}" />
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

loginBean

```
 package login;
 import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
 import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
 import java.sql.*;


 @ManagedBean(name="login")
 @SessionScoped
 public class loginBean {
 private String userName;
 private String password;
 private String label1;
 private String dbpwd;
 private String dbusername;

 private static int numOfAttempts = 0;
/** Creates a new instance of loginBean */
public loginBean() {
}

/**
 * @return the userName
 */
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

/**
 * @param userName the userName to set
 */
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

/**
 * @return the password
 */
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

/**
 * @param password the password to set
 */
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

/**
 * @return the label1
 */
public String getLabel1() {
    return label1;
}

/**
 * @param label1 the label1 to set
 */
public void setLabel1(String label1) {
    this.label1 = label1;
}

        Connection con;
    Statement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    String SQL_Str;

    public void dbData(String UName)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306  
                /securelogin","root","root");
            ps = con.createStatement();
            SQL_Str="Select * from tblusers where tbluserName =('" + UName +"')";
            rs=ps.executeQuery(SQL_Str);
            rs.next();
            dbusername=rs.getString("tbluserName");
            dbpwd=rs.getString("txtPassword");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception Occur :" + ex);
        }
    }


 public String checkLogin()
 {
      dbData(userName);
     if (userName.equals(dbusername) && password.equals(dbpwd))
    {
        this.setLabel1("Login Success");
        return "loginsuccess";
    }
    else
    {
        numOfAttempts++;
        if (numOfAttempts >= 3)
        {
        this.setLabel1("Account Locked");
        return "loginlocked";
        }
        else
        {
            this.setLabel1("Login Failure" + numOfAttempts + dbusername + dbpwd +    
             userName + password);
             return "loginfailure" ;
        }
    }
 }






}
```

Comment: what does the statck trace shows??

Answer (score 3):

Several things are not correct in your code:

- **NEVER USE** String concatenation when constructing SQL statments for JDBC. Instead, use parameters.

For example:

```
String sql = "Select * from users where username = ?";
```

means that the `?` symbol will be replaced with a given by you value. This is how it's made:

```
Statement statement = conn.createStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, username);
```

where `username` a String parameter. This is the proper way for creating SQL statement without the danger of SQL injections.

- As I can see from your code in the `dbData()` method, you forgot to close the connection and the statement, as well ... It is **very**important, because it releases the Connection/Statement object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for this to happen when it is automatically closed. It is generally good practice to release resources as soon as you are finished with them to avoid tying up database resources..

Additional information:

- [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)